# find element by xpath with selenium webdriver using python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to upload the file on onedrive with python. But i am unable to locate Upload button. Element found with xpath in driver but while writing in code it throws timeout exception.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="CommandBarItem beak-anchor command is-focused" data-bind="css: { 'is-toggled': isOpen() || isToggled(), 'is-disabled': isDisabled, 'is-disabled-invisible': isInvisibleWhenDisabled, 'is-open': isOpen, 'is-focused': focused, 'CommandBarItem--hasPayload': $component.hasPayload, 'icon-only': hasIconOnly, 'is-current-view': isCurrentView, 'is-pivot': isCurrentView !== null, 'is-last-pivot': isLastPivot }, class: commandClass() ? 'od-Command--' + commandClass() : '', hasFocus: isActive, raiseEventOnChange: { eventName: 'layoutChange', bubbleEvent: true, data: layoutChanged }, dismiss: { isOpen: isOpen, isAutomatic: payload &amp;&amp; payload.autoDismiss, timeout: payload &amp;&amp; payload.timeout, dismissOnResize: false, dismissOnScroll: false }, with: targetCommand(), attr: { tabindex: tabindex, role: role, 'aria-label': $parent.accessibleLabel, 'aria-haspopup': visibleChildren().length > 0 || !!payload, 'aria-selected': isOpen(), 'aria-pressed': isToggled(), 'data-automationid': automationId, 'aria-expanded': visibleChildren().length > 0 ? isOpen().toString() : false, id: newFeatureExperienceAnchor }, teachingBubble: teachingBubble, tooltip: { content: $data.tooltip, isTooltipDisabled: isOpen }" tabindex="0" role="menuitem" aria-label="Upload. Upload files from your computer to this location" aria-haspopup="true" data-automationid="" aria-expanded="false">
   <div class="CommandBarItem-linkWrapper">
      <div class="CommandBarItem-link" data-bind="measure: { measure: $parent.measurementReady, async: true }, click: onClick, automation: 'link'" data-automationid="link">
         <!--ko if: $parent.icon--><span class="CommandBarItem-icon" data-bind="component: { name: 'od-icon-glyph', params: { icon: $parent.icon, badge: $parent.iconBadge } }, attr: { 'is-flipped': $parent.positionIconRight }"><i class="od-IconGlyph ms-Icon ms-Icon--Upload css-46 od-IconGlyph--visible" data-bind="class: iconClasses, attr: { 'data-icon-name': icon }, css: { 'od-IconGlyph--badged': badge, 'od-IconGlyph--visible': icon }, with: badge" data-icon-name="Upload"></i></span><!--/ko--><!--ko if: $parent.iconUrl--><!--/ko--><!--ko if: $parent.label()--><span class="CommandBarItem-commandText" data-bind="text: $parent.label, attr: { 'is-flipped': $parent.positionIconRight, 'role': $parent.hasDynamicText ? 'status' : null, 'aria-live': $parent.hasDynamicText ? 'polite' : null }, css: { 'CommandBarItem-commandText--isStrong': $parent.isStrong, 'ms-accessible': $parent.hasIconOnly() || !$parent.isLabelVisible() }">Upload</span><!--/ko--><!--ko if: visibleChildren().length && !hidesMenuChevron && !isCollapsed() && $parent.isLabelVisible()--><i class="od-CommandBarItem-down ms-Icon css-47" data-bind="class: getChevronDown()"></i><!--/ko-->
      </div>
      <!--ko if: $data.inputType() === ActionInputType.htmlFileUpload--><!--/ko--><!--ko if: $data.inputType() === ActionInputType.folderUpload--><!--/ko-->
   </div>
   <!--ko if: children().length && isOpen() && !isClipped()--><!--/ko--><!--ko if: $component.hasPayload--><!--/ko-->
</div>
```

**My code:**

```
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
try:
 df = wait.until ( EC.presence_of_element_located ( (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="appRoot"]//div[@class="CommandBarItem beak-anchor command is-focused" and @aria-label="Upload. Upload files from your computer to this location"]')))
 df.click ()
 print (df)
except TimeoutException:
    print ( "page time to load" )
```

But it does not work and throws the time out exception

Comment: What happens if you try to debug this on your own? There should be some kind of XPATH extension for every browser out there to see whether your query matches

Comment: Why are you `driver.implicitly_wait(30)` when you have a `wait.until` there? Look at the `<span>` tag for the _Upload_ link.

Comment: if i remove driver.implicitly it also throws timeout error

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround that you can get location of the element and click on that element using the location. Or you can try calling onclick method using javascript executer .